# Basics of Tensor theory

Tags: tensor-calculus, vector-fields

Consider that we have an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$

We know that $e_2 \times e_3 = \pm e_1$, to show this in terms of tensor notation, from the Continuum Mechanics  by Chadwick textbook it is given as,

$e_2 \times e_3 = \{ (e_2 \times e_3).e_p\}e_p = \big[e_2,e_3,e_p\big]e_p = \big[e_2,e_3,e_1\big]e_1$

where,

$\big[e_2,e_3,e_1\big]$ is the scalar tipple product.

What is this step?

$e_2 \times e_3 = \{ (e_2 \times e_3).e_p\}e_p$

what operation is being done between the $(vector . e_p)e_p$, specifically what is the operation

> $.e_p\}e_p$

How can it be said that the expression below is the same as the cross product of two unit vectors that are normal to one another? (is, there any way of expanding this)

> $\big[e_2,e_3,e_1\big]e_1$

Or, is this any sign convention that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if $\{{\bf e}_p\}_{p=1}^3$ forms a basis, then you can write *any* vector as

$$
{\bf v} = v_1 {\bf e}_1 + v_2 {\bf e}_2 + v_2 {\bf e}_3 = v_p {\bf e}_p \tag{1}
$$

Moreover, if $\{{\bf e}_p\}_{p=1}^3$ forms an orthonormal set ${\bf e}_i \cdot {\bf e}_j = \delta_{ij}$ then

$$
v_j = {\bf v}\cdot {\bf e}_j \tag{2}
$$

So that (1) becomes

$$
v = ({\bf v}\cdot {\bf e}_p) {\bf e}_p = {\bf v}\cdot {\bf e}_p {\bf e}_p
$$

Now replace ${\bf v} = {\bf e}_2 \times {\bf e}_3$

Comment: So, The thing in the bracket $(\vec(v) . e_p)$ produces the component in any arbitrary direction $e_p$ and the and its product with $e_p$ would give that particular vector.

Comment: @Raptor Exactly, ${\bf v}\cdot {\bf e}_p$ gives you the length, and ${\bf e}_p$ gives you the direction

Comment: and the $\big[ e_2, e_3, e_1\big]$ would produce a product based on the sequence of i,j,k and so, $e_p$ will just get a scalar value attached to it. If I am not wrong.

Comment: @Raptor Yes, the result would be the scalar $[e_2, e_3, e_1]$ in the direction of ${\bf e}_1$. Spoiler: $[e_2, e_3, e_1]$ turns out to be an oriented volume defined by these three vectors

Comment: @Raptor for the dot product, please use \cdot command, e.g. $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{e}$. Using a period for a dot product was throwing me off.